# Explanation about i//2 in positional encoding in tensorflow tutorial about transformers

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, encoding, transformer, attention-mechanism

I was implementing the transformer architecture in tensorflow.

I was following the tutorial : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#setup_input_pipeline

They implement the positional encoding in this way:

```
angle_rates = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i//2)) / np.float32(d_model))
```

However in the paper i is not divided by 2 (i//2), is this a bug? , or why is the reason to make this operation?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, although they added some confusion with this trick. They should better call their argument $j$ instead of $i$, cos what they actually do is they take all values $0 \leq j \leq d_{model} - 1$ and compute $PE(pos, j)$. $j$ сan be either even or odd, but in the right side of the equation it's even, that's why they compute `i//2` and multiply back by 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should understand the equation like this:
When the dimension(i) is even, we calculate the position encoding like
[image]

But when the dimension is odd, we should make the calculation using the former index which means when we calculate the value of dimension 3， we should take 2 into the equation as the parameter i.

I recommend to read the simple code in [a-gentle-introduction-to-positional-encoding-in-transformer-models-part-1](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-positional-encoding-in-transformer-models-part-1/). The author realize the postion encoding as :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
def getPositionEncoding(seq_len, d, n=10000):
    P = np.zeros((seq_len, d))
    for k in range(seq_len):
        for i in np.arange(int(d/2)):
            denominator = np.power(n, 2*i/d)
            P[k, 2*i] = np.sin(k/denominator)
            P[k, 2*i+1] = np.cos(k/denominator)
    return P
 
P = getPositionEncoding(seq_len=4, d=4, n=100)
print(P)
```

in the second `for` loop, the index range is [0,int(d/2)]
For example， when we have dimension 4 [0,1,2,3], the index range is [0,2] which is [0,1,2]. When the i is 2, we calculate the values for dimension 2 and 3 and they have the same denominator. This is consistant with what I am saying `when the dimension is odd, we should make the calculation using the former index`

This is my understanding way